# Issues with Configuring NLog to Send Emails on Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nlog

I'm attempting to configure NLog to send emails when errors occur in my project. I've followed various guides and documentation, but I'm having trouble getting the email sending functionality to work correctly.

Here's my current NLog configuration in a JSON file:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "NLog": {
      "IncludeScopes": true
    }
  },
  "NLog": {
    "throwConfigExceptions": true,
    "internalLogLevel": "Info",
    "internalLogFile": "${basedir}/internal-nlog.txt", // debug internal file
    "extensions": [
      { "assembly": "NLog.Extensions.Logging" },
      { "assembly": "NLog.Web.AspNetCore" }
    ],
    "variables": {
      "var_logdir": "c:/temp" // for a folder other than base dir
    },
    "default-wrapper": {
      "type": "AsyncWrapper",
      "overflowAction": "Block"
    },
    "targets": {
      "logfile": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${basedir}/logs/applog-${shortdate}.log"
      },
      "logfileError": {
        "type": "File",
        "fileName": "${basedir}/logs/applog-exception-${shortdate}.log"
      },
      "logconsole": {
        "type": "ColoredConsole",
        "useDefaultRowHighlightingRules": "false",
        "rowHighlightingRules": [
          {
            "condition": "level == LogLevel.Info",
            "foregroundColor": "White"
          },
          {
            "condition": "level == LogLevel.Warn",
            "foregroundColor": "DarkYellow"
          },
          {
            "condition": "level == LogLevel.Error",
            "foregroundColor": "Red"
          },
          {
            "condition": "level == LogLevel.Fatal",
            "foregroundColor": "Red"
          }
        ]
      },
      "database": {
        "type": "Database",
        "connectionString": "${configsetting:ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}", // same as application db
        "keepConnection": "true",
        "dbProvider": "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient",
        "commandText": "insert into dbo.Logs ( Application, Logged, Level, Message, Logger, CallSite, Exception ) values ( @application, @logged, @level, @message, @logger, @callsite, @exception );",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "@application",
            "layout": "${processname}"
          },
          {
            "name": "@logged",
            "layout": "${date}"
          },
          {
            "name": "@level",
            "layout": "${level}"
          },
          {
            "name": "@message",
            "layout": "${message}"
          },
          {
            "name": "@logger",
            "layout": "${logger}"
          },
          {
            "name": "@callSite",
            "layout": "${callsite:filename=true}"
          },
          {
            "name": "@exception",
            "layout": "${exception:tostring}"
          }
        ]
      },
      "mail": {
        "type": "Mail",
        "subject": "Errore nell'applicazione",
        "from": "blabla.mailer@blabla.com",
        "to": "recipient@example.com",
        "smtpServer": "blabla.blabla.com",
        "smtpPort": 587,
        "smtpUserName": "blabla",
        "smtpPassword": "(blabla2^",
        "enableSsl": false
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "logconsole"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Info",
        "writeTo": "database"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Debug",
        "writeTo": "logfile"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Error",
        "writeTo": "logfileError"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Fatal",
        "writeTo": "logfileError"
      },
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Error",
        "writeTo": "mail"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I've tried various permutations, but I haven't achieved the desired results. I'm not receiving emails when errors occur in my project.

How should I configure NLog correctly for email notifications on errors? What steps or configurations am I likely missing?

Additionally, if there is documentation available on how to configure appsettings for email notifications with NLog, I'd greatly appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: When troubleshooting NLog then one should look in [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) for clues. Also enabling `"throwConfigExceptions": true` is a good idea. Maybe your application exits (or crashes) without doing flush/shutdown of NLog (not completing the sending of email). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting